# What is Copy-Editing?

Tags: editing

I know that `proof reading`is when someone read an article over and over again to fix grammar mistake(s) and or spelling error(s). But I am somehow confused that what the difference is with `copy-editing`? Is there something additional in copy-editing or is it something entirely different?

Comment: ***The Difference Between Copyediting and Proofreading***: 
http://www.dailywritingtips.com/the-difference-between-copyediting-and-proofreading/

Comment: @Josh61 based on the article you suggested me to read, it seems that in copy-editing, there is nothing about finding grammatical or spelling errors? In other words, the `semantic` of the article is addressed in copy-editing? Did I get it right?

Comment: No, lonesome; you need to read Josh's link again and much more slowly, please… particularly the bit saying: *… that the writing adheres to the conventions of grammar*, and that wording is proper and precise and punctuation is appropriate and correctly placed.

The writer is meant not to make mistakes; the copy editor is meant to pick up and correct mistakes that do get made; the proof-reader is meant to check that the test print - proof - matches what the copy editor sent to the type-setter, and two caveats.

More…

Comment: While type-setters can still be found they tend to be confined to the tiny number of specialist printing houses still using antique presses to produce exclusive items such as luxurious invitations.

With or without that limitation a proof-reader will doubtless *flag* mistakes but unlike the copy-editor, shouldn’t automatically *correct* mistakes which do match the original.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is at what stage in production editorial process each step occurs.

Copy editing involves revising an early stage draft or manuscript for format, style and accuracy before it is typeset.  A copy editor is looking chiefly to correct or improve the work of the writer.

Proofreading literally means to check the galley proof for errors. A proof is what you make on a printing press or printer so you can see how the typesetting will actually come out. A proofreader is looking chiefly for mistakes made by the typesetter.